# Placeholder on multiple textboxes

Tags: c#, textbox, placeholder

I'm using the following functions to create placeholder effect on a text box and it's working fine.

Now, I want to use this on multiple text boxes. Since I had only one box, the `placeholder` variable was enough. With multiple boxes, I need multiple placeholder strings. Is there a way to add custom property to a text box, so that I can access it from the placeholder functions?

```
public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Placeholder_Show(DomainBox, null);
}

public static string placeholder = "example.com";

private void Placeholder_Hide(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var box = sender as TextBox;
    if (box.Text == placeholder)
    {
        box.Text = "";
        box.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        box.Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 10.2F, FontStyle.Regular);
    }
}

private void Placeholder_Show(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var box = sender as TextBox;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(box.Text))
    {
        box.Text = placeholder;
        box.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
        box.Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 10.2F, FontStyle.Italic);
    }
}
```

Desired code (example):

```
textBox1.placeholder = "some";
textBox2.placeholder = "string";

private void Placeholder_Hide(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var box = sender as TextBox;
    if (box.Text == box.placeholder) // placeholders are associated with boxes
    {
        box.Text = "";
        box.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        box.Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 10.2F, FontStyle.Regular);
    }
}

private void Placeholder_Show(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var box = sender as TextBox;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(box.Text))
    {
        box.Text = box.placeholder;
        box.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
        box.Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 10.2F, FontStyle.Italic);
    }
}
```

---

<sub>I'm not that familiar with C#. Perhaps, there's a better way to deal with this.</sub>

Comment: You could extend `TextBox` class and implement this in your new class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i add a new Function or Property on textbox class's text property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697648/how-can-i-add-a-new-function-or-property-on-textbox-classs-text-property)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I've noticed that you can create custom controls. I decided to create a custom text box with placeholder effect so I wouldn't have to bother next time I need something like this.

Added a new class file: `CustomControls.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CustomControls
{
    public class CustomTextBox : TextBox
    {
        private string _placeholder;

        public string Placeholder
        {
            get { return this._placeholder; }
            set {
                this._placeholder = value;
                this.Placeholder_Show(null, null);
            }
        }

        public CustomTextBox()
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        private void Initialize()
        {
            this.Enter += new EventHandler(this.Placeholder_Hide);
            this.Leave += new EventHandler(this.Placeholder_Show);
        }

        private void Placeholder_Hide(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.Text == this._placeholder)
            {
                this.Text = "";
                this.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                this.Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 10.2F, FontStyle.Regular);
            }
        }

        private void Placeholder_Show(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Text))
            {
                this.Text = this._placeholder;
                this.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
                this.Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 10.2F, FontStyle.Italic);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edited the designer file: `MainForm.Designer.cs` (didn't want to create a new text box)

Changed

```
this.DomainBox = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
```

into

```
this.DomainBox = new CustomControls.CustomTextBox();
```

---

Now, this new `CustomTextBox` appears in the Toolbox under the name "[namespace] Components" at the top. You can just drag & drop it the same way you'd a normal text box. Also, you can access the `Placeholder` property in the Properties window under the name Misc.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, you could subclass the `Textbox` and add that functionality. This is probably the best option in general, but what if you want to use several unrelated tweaks like this? Another option is to implement it in a similar fashion to an `ErrorProvider`. You'll note that this component adds a property to other controls on the form. This is done through an [extender provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6c1xa43.aspx).